# VBS Removing files within a directory using FileSystemObject with exceptions?

Tags: oracle, vbscript

I work with the rather finnicky Oracle Business Intelligence software and we often have issues that entail, clearing out specific data on users systems, and then synchronizing with the server to pull down the data again. I've got a vbs script that I'm working on that removes key directories, and renames others and stops services etc.

Where I'm stuck is on one specific directory. Using FileSystemObject, what would be the easiest way to remove every single file within a directory with the exception of a single folder?

So, for this specific example, I have C:\OracleBIData\sync\config

Where I want to delete everything inside of the "sync" directory, with the exception of the config directory. Any takers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet:

```
Option explicit

Const folderspec = "C:\OracleBIData\sync"
Const excludeFolder = "C:\OracleBIData\sync\config"

deleteSubFolders CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(folderspec), excludeFolder   

Public Sub deleteSubFolders(byRef MyFolder, exclFolder)
    Dim sf
    For Each sf in MyFolder.SubFolders
        If not (lCase(sf.Path) = lCase(exclFolder)) Then
            deleteSubFolders sf, exclFolder
            sf.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It will not delete folders under the excludeFolder.

Comment: AutomatedChaos, I'm way late on this one. Although I was able to solve my little issue, I just wanted to say thanks for the answer. Had some unfortunate family developments and haven't really returned to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force is all I can think of.

Walk through the directory item but item and delete it if it is not config. Or if this directory has lots and lots and lots of files, first run through deleting a*.*, b*.*, d*.* 25 times, and then walk through the rest of the items.